# Python argparse: how to control line wrapping in help screen for subparsers?

Tags: python, python-3.6, argparse

I'm using Python 3.6.3 and have this piece of code:

```
import argparse
from argparse import RawTextHelpFormatter

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='foobar',
                                     formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('-lf', '--logfile', dest='logfile', default='/dev/null',
                    help='some very long help message goes here ..............................\n' +
                   'more text here xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
abcd_parser = subparsers.add_parser('abcd')

abcd_parser.add_argument('zzz', nargs='+',
                         help='A very long help message\ngoes here...... more help text goes here zzzzzzz   zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz  ')


args = parser.parse_args()
```

The help output looks like:

```
$ ./foobar  -h
usage: foobar [-h] [-lf LOGFILE] {abcd} ...

positional arguments:
  {abcd}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -lf LOGFILE, --logfile LOGFILE
                        some very long help message goes here ..............................
                        more text here xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The above output doesn't wrap the help text, as expected (except where i explicitly put in "\n")

However, the help output for the subparser looks like:

```
$ ./foobar  abcd  -h
usage: foobar abcd [-h] zzz [zzz ...]

positional arguments:
  zzz         A very long help message goes here...... more help text goes
              here zzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

1. How can i get the "goes here" to be printed on a new line (i specified "\n" but that didn't work)
2. How can i disable the line wrap so that the entire help text for the "zzz" argument is on one line?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands - says `add_parser`  takes `any ArgumentParser constructor arguments`,  I suppose it could be more explicit (the topic has come up in a bug/issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the subparser the same `formatter_class` you gave to the main parser, which you can do by passing `formatter_class` to `add_parser`:

```
abcd_parser = subparsers.add_parser('abcd', formatter_class=RawTextHelpFormatter)
```